# How to extend listControl class in C++ and add new functions?

Tags: c++, mfc, extend, listcontrol

Hi I need to extend the CListControl class in C++/MFC, which will add several new features in the list control, 
Any one have good sample code ?
Or could you please tell me how can i start it ?
Thanks in advance!

Or just write the new features and listControl into a ActiveX or COM ??
Which is better ?

Comment: What sort of functionality do you wish to add?

Comment: for example: setDataSource and SetSQL, and it will automatically load data from database and generate the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO add functionality such as you suggest in your comments above I wouldn't even make a derivation of CListCtrl.  It would make more sense, IMO, to create a CListCtrlManager class that handles things such as you suggest and then handles populating an associated CListCtrl.

Thing is if you wish to derive from a CListCtrl then it is USUALLY done for handling owner draw.  There is very little functionality that REQUIRES a derivation. For example I have a derived list ctrl that provides row colouring based on certain information as well as a checkbox in the list view.  To handle that I had to set the owener draw flag and handle list ctrl drawing directly, but you do not need to make a derivation to handle the functionality you desire.